# Telnet won't work on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, telnet

I'm using Windows 8.1 64bit.

I know how [enable Telnet-Client on Windows 8.1](http://www.sysprobs.com/install-and-enable-telnet-in-windows-8-use-as-telnet-client).

But when I type in :

`telnet microsoft.com 80`

nothing happens!

[image]

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: switch to Putty.  It is a better telnet client and does SSH.

Comment: try seeing what's happening in wireshark

Comment: @Keltari yeah it's still pretty bad though in terms of features.. the command line interface is so limited with putty, that things like saving a profile, can be done in the gui but not in the command line. so putty's gui is more powerful than its command line. but yeah it's better than telnet. Do mention if you have a better client than putty.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following:

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

Comment: I tried your command but nothing changed !

Comment: @HamedKamrava, what is the architecture of the machine you are trying this from?

Comment: x64-based processor

Comment: @HamedKamrava Does that return immediately back to the command prompt or does it flash the cursor for a few seconds

Comment: Immediately back to command prompt

Comment: @HamedKamrava what happens when you type just telnet?

Comment: same as first post. Immediately back to command prompt

Comment: Can you try deselecting it from windows features and then rebooting and trying again

Comment: I did. After deselecting `Telnet Client` and restarting windows, error is `'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: Its not installing properly for some reason. Can you do pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient" then pkgmgr /ui:"TelnetClient"

Comment: Second command gets me [this error](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/3716139747291626222_Untitled.png).

Comment: I'm out, use putty :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to install additional components into Windows:

**Settings > Control Panel**

Go to the **Programs** category.

In **Programs and Features**, choose "Turn Windows features on or off".

A dialog box appears with a list of programs and a check-box next to each one. Scroll down the list to find "Telnet Client" and tick the box.

Then click **OK** to apply the changes.

Comment: As I mentioned in the first post, I did enabled "Telnet Client"...

Comment: Ah, sorry. That is very unusual. No message? Just straight back to the prompt? I'd expect a "Connecting to ..." or a blank window with a blinking cursor.

Comment: Unfortunately there no errors :(

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  To fix it, I just removed it via Add/Remove Windows Features, and then added it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling telnet client by using [DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh824821.aspx) command:

```
dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
dism /Online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

See also: [Install Telnet Client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx) page.